# Asyncwebserver how to send inline HTML code?

Tags: html, arduino, wifi, esp32

Trying to run inline HTML code using Asyncwebserver without a "GET" request.

Working HTML file on Windows pc:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>
<head>
<title>README</title>
</head>
<body>

<div><object data="c:\users\1234\Desktop\LOG06242021.TXT" width="100%" height="800"></object></div>

<br><h2><a href=http://10.0.0.100:8030/Weather >Home</a>

</body>
</html>
```

All my attempts have failed to get this to work with Asyncwebserver. I have a variable that is a filename (fn).  Filename is extracted in notFound function and currently displays the LOG file with "request->send(SPIFFS, fn, String(), false)."  Trying with inline HTML code to display LOG files and add a hyperlink back to list of LOG file links.   Log files are created every 24 hours; reason for wanting a variable for filenames.

notFound function --latest attemp 06/28:

```
void notFound(AsyncWebServerRequest *request)
{

  digitalWrite(online, HIGH);   //turn-on online LED indicator

  if (! request->url().endsWith(F(".TXT")))
  {
    request->send(404);
  }
  else
  {
    if (request->url().endsWith(F(".TXT")))
    {
      //.endsWith(F(".txt")))

      // here comes some mambo-jambo to extract the filename from request->url()
      int fnsstart = request->url().lastIndexOf('/');

      fn = request->url().substring(fnsstart);


      PATH = fn;

      accessLog();

      Serial.print("File:  ");
      Serial.println(fn);

      File webFile = SPIFFS.open(fn);

      Serial.print("File size: ");

      Serial.println(webFile.size());

      if (!webFile)
      {

        Serial.println("File:  " + fn + " failed to open");
        Serial.println("\n");

      }
      else if (webFile.size() == 0)
      {

        webFile.close();

      }
      else
      {

        /* 
        String resp = "<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><title>Observations</title></head><body>";
        resp += "<div><object type='text/html' data=";
        resp += fn;   //filename from root directory listing of SdBrowse page.
        resp += "width='100%' height='800'></object></div>";
        resp += "<br><h2><a href=http://10.0.0.100:8030/SdBrowse >SdBrowse</a></body></html>";
                          
        AsyncWebServerResponse *response = request->beginResponse(200, "text/html", resp);
        response->addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin","*");
        request->send(response);
        */    //This only adds hyperlink; no display of text file

        //request->send(SPIFFS, fn, String(), true);  //Download file
        request->send(SPIFFS, fn, String(), false);  //Display file  <---- this works; text only
        
        webFile.close();          
        
      }

      fn = "";

      end();

    }    

  }

  digitalWrite(online, LOW);   //turn-off online LED indicator

}
```

[Project web site](http://weather-3.ddns.net/Weather)

[ESP32_Rain_Gauge Code](https://github.com/Tech500/RainGauge)

Comment: `String displayFile = ("http:\\10.0.0.100:8030" + fn);` I doubt you wanted a backslash in there.  That said, I don't really understand the question.

Comment: I also don't understand your call to `response->printf()` which gives a second argument that's never used via a format instruction like `%s`. I also don't really understand the question. If you could clarify what you're trying to make happen and what's actually happening that would help - actual output rather than descriptions are much more clear.

Comment: Trying to add a link to the bottom of a text file.  Working HTML file for Windows pc does exactly what I am trying to accomplish.  I am a  73 year old, novice with Asyncwebserver; not sure of how to accomplish task.

Comment: Compiles with no errors, produces url Link at bottom of web page; however, no text is displayed.

Comment: I'm not sure what the project website link is for, but it doesn't respond in Firefox.  Without complete code I cannot compile your project and I have no ESP32, so no means of running it even if I could; at best I would have to adapt it for ESP8266.  You could try migrating the question to arduino.stackexchange.com.  There are likely more people there paying attention an have an ESP32.  But to test they will still need all the relevant code.  The less code they need to replicate the problem the better.

Comment: Added project code; will only run ESP32.  Crashes on ESP8266.                      

Web site for project:  http://weather-3.ddns.net/Weather

Comment: Is your target board ESP8266 or ESP32? ESP8266 [ESPAsyncTCP](https://github.com/me-no-dev/ESPAsyncTCP) is different from ESP32 [AsyncTCP](https://github.com/me-no-dev/AsyncTCP).

Answer (score 0):

Here is code I am using to add header, text area, and hyperlink:

"HTML6":

```
const char HTML6[] PROGMEM = R"====(
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Show</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
.main
{
  type: text/txt;
  font-size:18px;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  margin: 30px;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>

    <h2>Observations
    <!-- <a href="/Show"><button>Show Log File</button></a> -->
    <br>
    <br>
    <div class="main" style="white-space: pre-wrap;" type="text/txt" id=file-content></div>
    <!-- <p style="white-space: pre-wrap;"id="file-content"></p>  -->
    <br>  
    <a href=http://%LINK%/SdBrowse >SdBrowse</a></h2><br>    
    
</body>
<script>  //JavaScript example by Sara Santos of [rnl.com/Forum][1]
  window.addEventListener('load', getFile);
  function getFile(){
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() 
    {
      if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) 
      {
        console.log(this.responseText);
        document.getElementById("file-content").innerHTML=this.responseText;
      }
    };
  xhr.open("GET", "/get-file", true);
  xhr.send();
}
</script>
</html>
)====";
```

---

Request "/Show " //Loads HTML6

```
serverAsync.on("/Show", HTTP_GET, [](AsyncWebServerRequest * request)
{

PATH = "/Show";
accessLog();

if (! flag == 1)
{
  
  request->send_P(200, PSTR("text/html"), HTML6, processor6);
  
}
end();
});
```

Request to get text file for HTML6:

```
serverAsync.on("/get-file", HTTP_GET, [](AsyncWebServerRequest *request){
request->send(SPIFFS, fn, "text/txt");
});
```

---

Request to get redirect from "notFound" function:

```
serverAsync.on("/redirect/internal", HTTP_GET, [](AsyncWebServerRequest *request){
request->redirect("/Show"); //recevies HTML request to redirect
});
```

William